# how to read html file and render it inside an asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement

I was wondering if there is any way in C# to create a function which would call a preset html if the requirements are fulfilled.
Something like `if url=domainname/test get <P>This is a test page</p>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this command inside aspx page

```
<!--#include virtual ="test.html" -->
```

or make a redirect to `test.html`

```
Response.Redirect("test.html");
```

or make a transparent redirect

```
Server.Transfer("test.html");
```

or make a function that reads the html file and render it to the page.

```
txtTest.Text = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("test.html")).ToString();
```

where `txtTest` is `<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="txtTest"></asp:Literal>` literal control on aspx page.

To make the include command inside aspx page you have to write it as

```
<%        
    if(Request.Url.ToString().Contains("http://url"))
    {        
%>    
        <!--#include virtual ="test.html"-->
<%
    }        
%>
```

Comment: interesting thank you very much for the input, i am still looking for a way to phrase the if condition based on the url of the page, then i could simply use the #include

Comment: @NecrosAeturnus this is the easy part `if (Request.Url.ToString().CompareTo("/this")) { }`

Comment: Could i ask you another quick question ? 
im using your if (Request.Url.ToString().Contains("/this")) { } but since my id's overflap, ../id-1 , .../id11, etc, is there a way to implement something like AbsolutePath ? thank you :)

Comment: @NecrosAeturnus Yes try the StartsWith https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @NecrosAeturnus Also the URL can give more, like the path as you say - use the visual studio to find them out